# Ghost in the machine, I guess!

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, slang

I'm trying to understand (as a non native english speaker) the meaning of the sentence in the title, and here is some frame: a man just went to a town while looking for an home and a series of mishaps prevent him from leaving it. While trying to leave a police car makes him pull over and eventually they arrest him because they suspect the car he's driving was stolen, so after some time he's in jail a police officer says the following:

> "Mr. Aikens, I'm afraid we owe you an apology. Seems this has all been one big mistake: the bulletin that your vehicle was stolen was supposedly originated with California Highway Patrol, but it seems we're the only department in the state that received it. Ghost in the machine, I guess!"

If this may help, the town is operated by an artificial intelligence system and there's no way they're gonna let him leave.

I need to translate this term to my native language so I think I might use a rephrasing :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "ghost in the machine" a widespread term?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/409969/is-ghost-in-the-machine-a-widespread-term)

Comment: @zhantongz: I had already seen that post, I just needed to know if this had a specific meaning in this context. My take would be something like "An error in the system, I guess"...

Comment: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+ghost+in+the+machine

Comment: Or Google it. Good Luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this context, *ghost in the machine* means that there is an unexpected result of the computer system.

When a non-sentient machine (or computer) expresses something beyond its mechanism, a different idiom is *a mind of its own*. For example,

> The system that reported your vehicle stolen seems to have a mind of its own.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/have-a-mind-of-its-own) says:

**have a mind of its own**

*mainly humorous*

> A machine or other object can be said to have a mind of its own if it seems to be controlling the way it behaves or moves, independently of the person using it:
>   *This shopping trolley has a mind of its own.*

Other terms (which may or may not translate well to your language) are *bug*, *glitch*, *defect*, *software defect*, *miskey*, or *typo*.